# How to use a Timer in java net game?

Tags: java, timer

1. I want to implement a puzzle net game in which there is a server who manages the game and the two clients. (Server is a socket based server with applet clients (swing clients)) 
   In more details I want to set timer for the two clients that will start at the same time, this is really important. The player which will manage to solve the puzzle will send his answer for a check on the server.
   The First who answered correctly will be declared as the winner of the round.
2. I didn't mention that at the first each player of the two needs to assemble a puzzle for his opponent and that should be done in a scope of 90 seconds (and to start at the same time).
   So I would like to know how to implement a count down timer also, and if there are some nice ways to show it on screen in an animated way.

Comment: I suggest you come back when you can formulate some *specific* questions about what problems you are having implementing all that.

Comment: It's quite simple and already written above, I need a timer how do I implement it on the server side? examples please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most games use the servers time so the clients only need to be given the time for displaying to the user.  The client can periodically ask the server how much time is left and display it in the gui.

Comment: Okay so, how can I do that is there some special class for timer?

Comment: I would use a ScheduledExecutorService http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html There is an older Timer class, however it doesn't has as many features.